# CCMenuItemImage change runtime cocos2d

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem

I have created a menuitem using

```
menuItemImage=[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"image_old.png" selectedImage:@"image_old.png" target:self selector:@selector(play)];
```

I am using below code to change the CCMenuItemImage but it isn't working. It say's incompatible pointer type sending 'CCTextured2D' to parameter of normalimage.

```
 [menuItemImage setNormalImage:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache]addImage:@"image_new.png"]];
```

How to change menuItemImage runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the normalImage with the following code. **I know this is not good practice but temporarily it works fine.**

```
[menuItemImage setNormalImage:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image_new.png"]];
```

I Hope it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is to make an extra menu item with nearly the same name
Change the state of the menuItems by swapping the visible property from false to true and vice versa

Example:

```
CCMenuItem *menuItemOn;
CCMenuItem *menuItemOff;

-(void)ChangeMenuItem{
menuItemOff = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"buttonOff.png" selectedImage: @"buttonOff.png"  target:self selector:@selector(Method_off)];
 itemJoinOff = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"buttonOn.png.png" selectedImage: @"buttonOn.png" target:self selector:@selector(Method_On)];
menuItemOff.visible = false;
menuITemOn.visible = true;
menuItemOff position ..... etc
}
```

Whenever the menu On/Off state must change, make MenuItemOn visible and menuItemOff unvisible.